# How many combinations of pennies, dimes, nickels, and quarters create 0.32$?

Tags: combinatorics

I need help solving this. I cannot find the complete number of combinations. I have already found $5$, but I can't find any more.

Comment: Which ones do you have?

Comment: 1 quarter, 12 pennies

Comment: A quarter is $25$ cents, not $20$.

Comment: That's 37 cents ...

Comment: oops I forgot  that they were 25

Comment: Look for nonnegative integral solutions of the linear equation $p+5n+10d+25q=32$.

Comment: What the heck does that mean I am only a 4th grader

Answer (score 1):

First consider quarters.  You could have either no quarters (leaving $32$ cents to be covered by pennies, nickels and dimes) or one quarter (leaving $7$ cents).  Diagram:

```
     (32) 
  [0 quarters]        [1 quarter]         
     (32)                (7)
```

Next, consider dimes.  In the first case you could have 0, 1 or 2 dimes, in the second you must have 0.  Diagram:

```
     (32)
  [0 quarters]                              [1 quarter]         
     (32)                                      (7) 
[0 dimes]    [1 dime]    [2 dimes]          [0 dimes]
  (32)         (22)         (2)                (7)
```

Next consider nickels.  Finally, everything left over must be done with pennies.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving out the pennies in each combo ...

There are 2 combos with a quarter:

25+5 (that is: 1 quarter + 1 nickel ...so 2 pennies...)

25 (So just a quarter ...so 7 pennies ...  for combos below, you'll have to figure out how many pennies to add ...)

There is 1 combo with 3 dimes:

10+10+10

There are 3 combos with 2 dimes:

10+10+5+5

10+10+5

10+10

There are 5 combos with 1 dime:

10+5+5+5+5

10+5+5+5

10+5+5

10+5

10

There are 7 combos without dimes or quarters:

5+5+5+5+5+5

5+5+5+5+5

5+5+5+5

5+5+5

5+5

5

(32 pennies)

Total: 18 combos

Comment: thanks for your help @Bram28

Comment: @SagePosko No problem ... do you see the way I created these combos so we can be sure there are no others?

Comment: yes I do, now I know what to do next time

Comment: can you help with another question?@Bram28

Comment: @SagePosko sorry, just saw your question. I would say if you have another question then just make that another post ... There are lots of people in the community that can help! :)